# Can I add a link to heading?

Tags: html

Can I add a link to heading in HTML? 
Something like this

```
<h2 href="/ingredients">illness</h2>
```

Somehow it seems to work on simple text only.

Comment: Only `a` and `link` elements have a `href` attribute. Adding this attribute to other elements does not make them links.

Comment: @Derek: How does that in any way add to the comment already posted by Felix? If you were posting your comment in a matter of minutes, whatever, but it's been 30 minutes since his comment.

Comment: @Truth - * extended explanation *

Comment: @FelixKling, @Derek - `<area>` and `<base>` also take an href attribute. On `<area>`, it makes a link.

Comment: @Alohci: Thanks (I rarely use these tags). You could also argue that `a` only becomes a link with an `href` attribute (otherwise, given a `name`, it is just an anchor). My point was that being or not being a link is a property of the element/tag (maybe in combination of a certain attribute) but never of an attribute alone.

Answer (score 20):

(Almost) All elements may contain other elements. So the following is possible:

```
<h2><a href="/ingredients">Illness</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to tag the `a` anchor tag inside your `h2` tag. something like this:

```
<h2><a href="/ingredients">illness</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes.

If you can't edit the destination page (e.g. to add an anchor, as per the other answers), you may not be out of luck.

For example, nothing like

`href="https://www.hospitalsafetygrade.org/h/ucsf-medical-center-moffitt-long-hospitals#Sepsis infection after surgery"`

will open that page and display the section with the heading

`<h3>Sepsis infection after surgery</h3>`

However, there's a new standard, scroll-to-text-fragment, see https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment, that can often accomplish this purpose.  For example,

[https://www.hospitalsafetygrade.org/h/ucsf-medical-center-moffitt-long-hospitals#:~:text=MRSA%20infection](https://www.hospitalsafetygrade.org/h/ucsf-medical-center-moffitt-long-hospitals#:%7E:text=MRSA%20infection)
works!

(But
[https://www.hospitalsafetygrade.org/h/ucsf-medical-center-moffitt-long-hospitals#:~:text=Sepsis%20infection%20after%20surgery](https://www.hospitalsafetygrade.org/h/ucsf-medical-center-moffitt-long-hospitals#:%7E:text=Sepsis%20infection%20after%20surgery)
doesn't work.)

To see how widespread support is, see https://wpt.fyi/results/scroll-to-text-fragment?label=experimental&label=master&aligned.